# Dropdown list items not printing - Internet Explorer 11 only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie-compatibility-mode

We have a very old application running that has stopped printing correctly when users hit it with IE11.  Displaying on the screen works, but when you print the page the content of all the dropdown boxes disappears as well as the little dropdown box arrows.
Works in FF and Chrome and IE10 or smaller just fine

On Screen it looks like this:

[image]

But the Print Preview in IE11 looks like this:

[image]

And it prints this way too. No down arrow graphic and no text in the dropdown.

The page is using a print.css.
Thought I would ask if anyone had seen this behavior before I started posting source code.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried turning on/off compatibility mode?

Comment: Ah ha. IE Compatibility Mode was on for all Intranet sites but off for all Internet sites. Client turned it off and bang it prints correctly. Turned it back on and the problem came back. Client deployed a group policy change to put things back in sync.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @stevepowell2000 You're stating that Compatibility View was *causing* problems for a site designed in an older version of Internet Explorer?